# Onclick function in loop using last iteration of loop instead of current iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Its supposed to loop through the array components and put a different argument each time depending on current loop iteration but it keeps using the last iteration of the loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
var x = document.createElement("div");
document.querySelector(".item").style.display = "none";
x.innerHTML = document.querySelector(".item").innerHTML;
x.className = "item";
x.id = products[i][5];
x = document.querySelector(".resultitems").appendChild(x);
document 
  .getElementById(products[i][5])
  .getElementsByTagName("a")[0].onclick = productNum(products[i][5]);
```

the entire loop was too long to post, but see the onclick function, it puts the last iteration every time
any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Is `productNum` returning a function or should `productNum` itself be executed upon click? Because right now `productNum` is executed and its return value is assigned to the onclick event.

Comment: its setting a local variable using a switch statement that's based on the argument

Comment: Try to change `productNum(products[i][5])` to `() => productNum(products[i][5]);`

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks alot Ivar I was trying to get it fixed for the last hour